# $in not comparing all values in golang using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I am using golang as a backend with mongodb

My Collections are

```
**department**
    {
     dept_id:1,
     dept_name:'CSE',
     dept_overview:'overview'
    }
   ................

**employee**
    {
    emp_id:1,
    emp_name:'abc',
    qualification:'PHD',
    emp_dept:'CSE',
    city:'xyz'
    }
    {
    emp_id:2,
    emp_name:'xyz',
    qualification:'PHD',
    emp_dept:['CSE','ME'],
    city:'xyz',
    status:1
    }
    ..........
```

Below is my Go code using pipeline

```
 var conditionParam []bson.M
        if city == "" {
            conditionParam = []bson.M{
                bson.M{"$eq": []string{"$$element.qualification", "PHD"}},
                bson.M{"$in": []interface{}{"$$element.emp_dept", ["CSE"]}},
                bson.M{"$or": []interface{}{"$$element.emp_dept", "CSE"}},
                bson.M{"$eq": []string{"$$element.city", "xyz"}},
                bson.M{"$or": []interface{}{"$exists", []interface{}{"$$element.status", false}}},
                bson.M{"$or": []interface{}{"$$element.status", 1}}, 
            }
    } else if(){
    --------------------
}

matchStage:=bson.M{"$match":bson.M{'dept_id':1}}
lookupStage:=bson.M{"$lookup": bson.M{
    "from":         "employee",
    "localField":   "dept_name",
    "foreignField": "emp_dept",
    "as":           "result_list",
}}
    pipeline := getCollection.Pipe([]bson.M{
            matchStage,
            lookupStage,
            {"$addFields": bson.M{
                "result_list": bson.M{
                    "$filter": bson.M{
                        "input": "$result_list",
                        "as":    "element",
                        "cond": bson.M{
                            "$and": conditionParam,
                        },
                    },
                },
            }},
        })
```

In my collection some of data stored in `string` for  `emp_dept` and some of the data stored in `string slice`. So I am using `$in` for comparing slice values and `$or` for string values for `emp_dept`.`$in` operator working for database string values but is not working for comparing `emp_dept` database values in slice. How we can return both values for slice and string for this particular key of mongodb collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I understood is, you need to filter the array by `$result_list.emp_dept` which is in two different type that are `string` and `array`. You can use `$type` to check whether it's an array or string. If the scenario is correct, the following query works fine. Since you have written the pipeline in `Go`, I hope you can convert the following query to `Go`. Bcs I'm not a `Go` developer.

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "employee",
      "localField": "dept_name",
      "foreignField": "emp_dept",
      "as": "result_list"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "result_list": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$result_list",
          cond: {
            $cond: [
              {
                $eq: [ { $type: "$$this.emp_dept" }, "string" ]
              },
              { // if the type is string
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [ "CSE", "$$this.emp_dept" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.qualification", "PHD" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.city", "xyz" ]
                  }
                  // Other comparison
                ]
              },
              {  // if the type is NOT string
                $and: [
                  {
                    $in: [ "CSE", "$$this.emp_dept" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.qualification", "PHD" ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [ "$$this.city", "xyz" ]
                  }
                  // Other comparison
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FzmTyjwi79-)

Comment: can we check type inside `$and` then use `$eq` and `$in` accordingly for `emp_dept` only because I have no of parameters for comparison. like if type=='string' then `$eq` else `$in`

Comment: Of course yes, You can check `$eq` and `$in` another stage

Comment: I want to use only one `$and` and compare type for dept inside it without effecting other elements but I did not understand how to do it?

Comment: You expect https://mongoplayground.net/p/whiMB9HbZSs    ???

Comment: $varman  where to compare the other element as `$cond` takes only 3 arguments?

Comment: since you need compare emp_dept in one stage, create another stage to compare other fileds. https://mongoplayground.net/p/wWTeil4sOJW